# In C++, are acquire-release memory order semantics transitive?

Tags: c++, concurrency

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), we can use release-acquire semantics to ensure write-read precedence between two threads as follows:

```
// Thread A
1. Write to X
2. Atomic store to Y with std::memory_order_release
// Thread B
3. Atomic load at Y with std::memory_order_acquire
4. Read at X
```

Supposing that `2` is ordered before `3` (take it as a given that this occurs according to Y), we are guaranteed that `A`'s write to `X` is visible to `B` since we can establish a total order on the events (as conveniently described by my enumeration above) because `1 sequenced-before 2 synchronizes-with 3 sequenced-before 4` and because release-acquire ensure that all of `A`'s writes are visible to `B` after `3`.

*However*, the link above explicitly states that in this situation "all memory writes (non-atomic and relaxed atomic) [by A become] visible side-effects in thread B." My question is then: **are "visible side-effects" considered writes made `B` to threads previously unaware of `A`'s writes?**

In other words, suppose I had a third thread `C` and another atomic:

```
// Thread A
1. Write to X
2. Atomic store to Y with std::memory_order_release
// Thread B
3. Atomic load at Y with std::memory_order_acquire
4. Read at X
5. Atomic store to Z with std::memory_order_release
// Thread C
6. Atomic load at Z with std::memory_order_acquire
7. Read at X
```

(Assume similarly that `5 happens-before 6`). Would `C` read `A`'s write to `X`? Or is `B`'s "visible side-effect" on `X` not considered a write?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formally, you are asking if the side effect on X in thread A is visible with respect to value computation of X in thread C.

For that to be true, 1 needs to happen-before 7.

A happens-before B is defined, as synchronizes-with or inter-thread happens-before, and the latter is defined as

> for some evaluation X,
>
> — A synchronizes with X and X is sequenced before B, or
>
> — A is sequenced before X and X inter-thread happens before B, or
>
> — A inter-thread happens before X and X inter-thread happens before B.

So yes, it is perfectly transitive across multiple threads. In particular, in your case,

1 sequenced-before 2

2 synchronizes-with 3

3 sequenced-before 5

5 synchronizes-with 6

6 sequenced-before 7

Therefore, 1 happens-before 7, therefore 1 is a visible side-effect with respect to 7, and therefore the value of non-atomic scalar object X as determined by the value computation of X (your "Read at X") is guaranteed to be the value stored by the visible side-effect 1.

Comment: Ah, so according to your second sentence, it is sufficient for a write on one thread to happen-before a read on another thread by _any_ chain of precedence for the value to be seen. Would you mind citing that claim, if I understood you correctly?

Comment: And, if you don't mind, since you heavily edited [this page regarding `atomic_...` overloads for `shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic), could you please tell me if you know of any compilers that actually support this feature? Many claim full C++11 support, but this is always undefined (I tried clang 3.4, gcc 4.8, and a few online compilers)...

Comment: @VF1 the citation is the one I quoted. And clang has had the shared_ptr atomics since 2011, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/613b848af2d3b571 (note that they are part of the library, you probably used clang with GNU library, which of course is not anywhere near C++11)